# How to access raw data from RenderTexture in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, framebuffer, rendertarget

### Short Version of Problem

I am trying to access the contents of a RenderTexture in Unity which I have been drawing with an own Material using Graphics.Blit.

```
Graphics.Blit (null, renderTexture, material);
```

My material converts some yuv image to rgb successfully, which I have tested by assigning it to the texture of an UI element. The result is the correct RGB image visible on the screen.

However, I also need the raw data for a QR code scanner. I am doing this like I would access it from a camera as explained [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/9969/convert-a-rendertexture-to-a-texture2d.html). In a comment down there, it was mentioned that the extraction is also possible from a RenderTexture that was filled with Graphics.Blit. But when I am trying to that, my texture only contains the value 205 everywhere. This is the code I am using in the Update function, directly after the Graphics.Blit call:

```
RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
texture.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
texture.Apply ();
RenderTexture.active = null;
```

When assigning this texture to the same UI element, it is gray and slightly transparent. When viewing the image values, they are all 205.

Why is the possible? May there be problems with the formats that the RenderTexture and Texture2D I am trying to fill?

### Complete Code

In the following I add the whole code I am using. The names of the variables slightly differ to the ones I used above but they do essentially the same:

```
/** 
 * This class continously converts the y and uv textures in 
 * YUV color space to a RGB texture, which can be used somewhere else
 */
public class YUV2RGBConverter : MonoBehaviour {
    public Material yuv2rgbMat;

    // Input textures, set these when they are available
    [HideInInspector]
    public Texture2D yTex;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Texture2D uvTex;

    // Output, the converted textures
    [HideInInspector]
    public RenderTexture rgbRenderTex;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Texture2D rgbTex;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Color32[] rawRgbData;

    /// Describes how often per second the image should be transferred to the CPU
    public float GPUTransferRate = 1.0f;
    private float timeSinceLastGPUTransfer = 0.0f;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    /**
     * Initializes the used textures 
     */
    void Start () {
        updateSize (width, height);
    }

    /**
     * Depending on the sizes of the texture, creating the needed textures for this class 
     */
    public void updateSize(int width, int height)
    {
        // Generate the input textures
        yTex = new Texture2D(width / 4, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        uvTex = new Texture2D ((width / 2) * 2 / 4, height / 2, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

        // Generate the output texture
        rgbRenderTex = new RenderTexture(width, height, 0);
        rgbRenderTex.antiAliasing = 0;
        rgbTex = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

        // Set to shader
        yuv2rgbMat.SetFloat("_TexWidth", width);
        yuv2rgbMat.SetFloat("_TexHeight", height);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the y and uv textures to some dummy data
     */
    public void fillYUWithDummyData()
    {
        // Set the y tex everywhere to time rest
        float colorValue = (float)Time.time - (float)((int)Time.time); 
        for (int y = 0; y < yTex.height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < yTex.width; x++) {
                Color yColor = new Color (colorValue, colorValue, colorValue, colorValue);
                yTex.SetPixel (x, y, yColor);
            }
        }
        yTex.Apply ();

        // Set the uv tex colors 
        for (int y = 0; y < uvTex.height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < uvTex.width; x++) {
                int firstXCoord = 2 * x;
                int secondXCoord = 2 * x + 1;
                int yCoord = y;

                float firstXRatio = (float)firstXCoord / (2.0f * (float)uvTex.width);
                float secondXRatio = (float)secondXCoord / (2.0f * (float)uvTex.width);
                float yRatio = (float)y / (float)uvTex.height;

                Color uvColor = new Color (firstXRatio, yRatio, secondXRatio, yRatio);
                uvTex.SetPixel (x, y, uvColor);
            }
        }
        uvTex.Apply ();
    }

    /**
     * Continuously convert y and uv texture to rgb texture with custom yuv2rgb shader
     */
    void Update () {
        // Draw to it with the yuv2rgb shader
        yuv2rgbMat.SetTexture ("_YTex", yTex);
        yuv2rgbMat.SetTexture ("_UTex", uvTex);
        Graphics.Blit (null, rgbRenderTex, yuv2rgbMat);

        // Only scan once per second
        if (timeSinceLastGPUTransfer > 1 / GPUTransferRate) {
            timeSinceLastGPUTransfer = 0;

            // Fetch its pixels and set it to rgb texture
            RenderTexture.active = rgbRenderTex;
            rgbTex.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
            rgbTex.Apply ();
            RenderTexture.active = null;

            rawRgbData = rgbTex.GetPixels32 ();
        } else {
            timeSinceLastGPUTransfer += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, sorry that I have to answer my question on my own. The solution is very easy:

The width and height property that I was using in this line:

```
rgbTex.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
```

where not initialized, so they where 0.

I just had to add those lines to the updateSize function:

```
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
```